# What difference does it make to backup PostgreSQL before or after vacuum?

Tags: postgresql

What is the difference between performing a PostgreSQL backup before vacuuming the DB compared to after vacuuming the DB?

Answer (score 4):

If your backup is done with `pg_dump` then there'll no difference. It might be *slightly* faster if you had lots of dead space leading to a better visibility and freespace map after vacuum, but generally not much.

If your backup is done with `pg_basebackup` or at the filesystem level then a `vacuum full` will reduce backup size. A regular `vacuum` generally won't make any difference.

If you plan to regularly `vacuum full`, consider setting a fillfactor of lower than 100% on your tables. Otherwise you'll take a serious performance hit on all regularly updated tables after each vacuum full run as PostgreSQL has to expand the tables it just shrunk.